# Create list of strings with fixed prefix based on size of a list

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, list-comprehension

I want to create a list of strings with a fixed prefix where the suffix is based on the size of a list, by using python 3.3.2.

For example I have a list `elements` with `len(elements)` equal to 3. The output should be a list `output = ['prefix_1','prefix_2','prefix_3']`

I can do this by using a loop:

```
elements = ['elem1','elem2','elem3']
output = []
for i in range(len(elements)):
    output.append('prefix_'+str((i+1)))
```

This works but seems a bit... unpythonic to me. Is there a more pythonic way to do this? For example with a list comprehension?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using [`enumerate`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate), [`str.format`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes#str.format):

```
>>> elements = ['elem1','elem2','elem3']
>>> output = ['prefix_{}'.format(i) for i, elem in enumerate(elements, 1)]
>>> output
['prefix_1', 'prefix_2', 'prefix_3']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
o = ["prefix_" + str(i+1) for i in range(len(elements))]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
output=['prefix_'+str(i+1) for i in range(len(['elem1','elem2','elem3']))]
```